# Adding a custom UIView to a UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

I have 3 buttons that I am trying to add as a custom header to some of the views in my application.  Adding them in the storyboard works just fine and I can hook them up to methods in the view controller.

I recently wanted to add these buttons to some other pages and wanted to abstract them out into a control that could be re-used on the different pages.  I have it setup but am having difficulty adding it using the normal method.

[image: Maybe this picture will help explain what I'm talking about]

Typically I add the view controller as a child view controller and then add the view as a subview, in this case I'm adding it to a placeholder that I have in the storyboard, code looks like this:

```
// Setup Header
HeaderViewController * headerViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HeaderViewController"];
[headerViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [headerViewController.view frame].size.width, [headerViewController.view frame].size.width)];
[_headerView addSubview:headerViewController.view];
```

This allows me to have the view looking correct however when I click on a button it crashes because it can't find the view controller that has the IBActions associated with the button click.  Normally I would add the following code and it would be taken care of:

```
[self addChildViewController:headerViewController];
```

In this case however I get an error stating:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller: should have parent view controller: but actual parent is:'

I understand this to mean that it thinks the parent of the custom header view controller should be navigation controller, setting it as a child of the navigation controller doesn't work either.  It adds the header view on top of the PageViewControllers view being displayed.  I'm probably missing something simple

Some of the combinations that I've tried work on the simulator but none of them work on the device, so if you play around with a similar configuration make sure to look at it on device if it appears to be working in the simulator.

Any thoughts or what information other information could be provided to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get this working using other methods suggested, not that they're wrong I just couldn't get them to work.

I ended up creating a UIView subclass with a corresponding xib and put the IBActions into the UIView subclass.  This required a weak link to the holding view controller in order to show the modal views appropriately for the IBAction triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Put your IBActions on the header view controller instead and bind them in the xib without referencing any other view controller.

Then, in the header view controller you can pass them down to it's parent. That way it's determining who recieves the action at runtime, not as part of your xib.

```
- (IBAction)button1Pressed {
    if ([self.parentViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(button1Pressed)])
        [self.parentViewController performSelector(button1Pressed)];
    else
        NSLog(@"Parent doesn't care about button 1 : %@", self.parentViewController);
}
```

You can also check to see if the parent can respond or not :)

Comment: Part of the reason for the move is to isolate the IBAction code associated with the buttons, for the most part they display a modal view.  The IBAction code is already included in the HeaderViewController, I guess I'm not quite understanding how your solution works.  Can you clarify?

Comment: If your header view controller's IBActions are already connected to the buttons' events then I don't see why it would try to call methods on other view controllers? Can you add the crash log to your question so we can see what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the response, it was helpful in getting to the answer but I couldn't make it work with what was described here and ended up going a different way.